# Barra de progreso, tomando dato del DOM(html)

Tags: html, css, angular

Quiero hacer unas barras de progreso editables desde el front de mi app (Angular). Es un portfolio sencillo, pero debe ser editable desde un Login.

La única forma que consegui para editar los datos de las barras de progreso fue ingresar datos, por ejemplo: definir el ancho de la barra en 50% desde el css; pero necesito que tome el dato desde el html (llamo este dato desde un DB), para luego en la app editarlo y de ésta manera la barra sea dinámica de acuerdo al dato que yo ingresé (del 1 al 100).

Les adjunto lo que necesito, y como tengo el html y css. Todo en Angular y bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 text-center col-sm-6 py-2">
  <div class="progress" id="progressBar">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-label="Example 1px high" id="progressBarPorcentaje" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">90%</div>
  </div>
  <h6>Angular</h6>
</div>
```

css

```
#progressBarPorcentaje{width: 50%;}
```

y lo que deseo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el progress-bar pones el atributo style="width: ALGUN_VALOR%", no veo el problema....

Comment: me piden que el valor del porcentaje (ejemplo: 35%) lo tome de alguna etiqueta del DOM. ya que ese dato vendra de base de dtos. para que al modificar la DB se modifique tanto la etiqueta (concatenada) como el css (stylo o ancho de la barra.)

Comment: Pero es que tu etiqueta del dom es el <div style="width: 35%" .....>